# BizTalk solution created in VS 2013 not opening in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

We have created a BizTalk Solution in VS 2013 Premium version. Now we have upgraded the Visual Studio version to VS 2015 Enterprise version. But when opening in VS 2015 it says BizTalk Project is incompatible. I went through [this MSDN article](http://BizTalk%20server%20projects%20are%20not%20compatible%20with%20Visual%20Studio%202015%20or%20Visual%20Studio%202013.). But its says

> BizTalk server projects are not compatible with Visual Studio 2015 or
> Visual Studio 2013.

We used BizTalk Server 2013 R2 for developing the BizTalk Solution. Do I need to reinstall BizTalk for solving this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each version of BizTalk is very specific about which version of Visual Studio it needs.  See [Visual Studio versions needed by each release of BizTalk](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amantaras/2010/04/21/visual-studio-versions-needed-by-each-release-of-biztalk/)

For BizTalk 2013 R2 you need Visual Studio 2013.  You cannot use Visual Studio 2015 for BizTalk 2013 R2.

You can use Visual Studio 2015 for BizTalk 2016 which at this time is in [community technology preview 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt670742), GA later this year

Answer (score 0):

Try to change MSI property when you using visual studio 2015.

[Will/Does Visual Studio 2013 support BizTalk 2013 projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670104/will-does-visual-studio-2013-support-biztalk-2013-projects/38598856#38598856)

That's might be solved your issue.