# Biztalk 2010 and Visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a BizTalk 2010 solution on visual studio 2010. I want to migrate this solution to visual studio 2015 and read an article on MSDN that BizTalk 2010 is not supported on visual studio 2015.  Did anyone try this migration? just want to check if BizTalk 2010 works with visual studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

Each version of BizTalk requires a specific version of Visual Studio.
As per the MSDN article it is not supported.

Don't try it.

I'm not aware of anyone trying it for BizTalk 2010, but there was one person that answered this question that got BizTalk 2013 to work with Visual Studio 2015. 
[Will/Does Visual Studio 2013 support BizTalk 2013 projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19670104/will-does-visual-studio-2013-support-biztalk-2013-projects)   But if you run into any issues, it will probably not be supported by Microsoft, and this may include issues in production.