# BizTalk Server 2013 R2 VS Visual studio 2015

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

Trying to install BizTalk server 2013 R2, I got developer tools and SDK gray out as below screen shot so, does BizTalk server 2013 R2 support visual studio 2015 for development of BizTalk application?

[image: Installation wizard]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BizTalk 2013 R2 does not support Visual Studio 2015. 
You would need to install Visual Studio 2013 to support BizTalk Server 2013 R2.

Please see this link to see the required versions for BizTalk 2013 and BizTalk 2013 R2:  [Hardware and Software Requirements for BizTalk Server 2013 and 2013 R2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248697.aspx)

Comment: FYI reference solution [link]http://stackoverflow.com/a/38598856/6766331

Comment: This is nice! Thank you for sharing.